# Would you like Gaming.SE merch with "classic" questions on them?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, swag

One thing the Gaming.SE has that other SE's don't seem to is an abundance of eye-catching, peculiar questions that, when taken out of context, are hilarious. These questions get a ton of views and get quickly linked and shared among communities (at least among the six members of CHAOS here at SE). Would anyone be interested in merchandise with some of the most interesting questions on them, with the Gaming.SE logo/url/etc. on it as well?

Some contenders for t-shirt/mug/etc immortality are:

- [So I was out drinking last night...how do I remove a tattoo?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22862/so-i-was-out-drinking-last-night-how-do-i-remove-a-tattoo)
- [My children are useless. What should I do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18376/my-children-are-useless-what-should-i-do)
- [How can I kill adorable animals?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24345/how-can-i-kill-adorable-animals)
- [When should I start drinking?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18105/when-should-i-start-drinking)
- [Dry eye from not blinking enough](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18220/dry-eye-from-not-blinking-enough) (not a question, but man do I love it)
- [My wife is stuck in a wall, can I save her?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5542/my-wife-is-stuck-in-a-wall-can-i-save-her)
- [How can I tell if a corpse is safe to eat?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-corpse-is-safe-to-eat)
- [How can I keep monsters out of my nether regions?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14605/how-can-i-keep-monsters-out-of-my-nether-regions)
- [Can I pass out from excessive drinking?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9768/can-i-pass-out-from-excessive-drinking)
- [How do I know if I'm dead?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11455/how-do-i-know-if-im-dead)
- [Why did my dog just eat my cat?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/17067/8366)
- [My pet is a public menace, what did I do wrong?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/26210/8366)
- [Why make cheese if milk is already food?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/27010/8366)
- [What is the most effective way to mock someone else's religion?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27580/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-mock-someone-elses-religion)

If you think this is a fun idea, please respond and say so. Also include any other questions that I may have missed (I know I definitely did).

**UPDATE:** I've edited this post to collect all the question suggestions. It's nice to have them all in one place, and also it makes me chuckle every time I come to this post. More importantly, there has been some discussion over in [The Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-b-ridge) about having **mousepads** instead of (or in addition to) mugs and t-shirts. If this sounds like a solid idea, let me know. We're still a step or two away from getting this done, but let it be known that it is on my mind daily (along with all my X-Men thoughts).

Comment: No love for our top question of all time? [How can I tell if a corpse is safe to eat?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-corpse-is-safe-to-eat)

Comment: Yes of course! I seriously spent a little while trying to remember what that question was. Thanks!

Comment: I tend to not be crazy about t-shirts, but other textually deserving swag seems like a huge win. In pipe dream land, I'd love a "When Should I Start Drinking" clock...

Comment: I think that such T-Shirts should contain the [Tags] on the question in question. Otherwise, hell yes!

Comment: This meme is what makes Gaming.SE so special. Putting our specialty in the eyes of the public is surely a good idea... Go for it!

Comment: Mousepad would be perfect.

Comment: How to pray safely (to God)?http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5089/how-to-pray-safely-to-god

Comment: I'm not terribly active here, so I didn't realize that this was already a thing, but I set up a Twitter account to collect these:

https://twitter.com/#!/gamingqs

I don't know if I'll add all these awesome ones listed here; I rather like the idea of adding them as they're asked and hit the front page. But it may be that I'm codifying something that should not be codified, or making it more likely for people to purposely ask ridiculous questions in hopes of making the list.

What say y'all: Should I keep going, or just delete the account?

Comment: @BrettWhite what about this one? How do I know who I slept with: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/58819/how-do-i-know-who-i-slept-with

Comment: [How can I kill myself?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159866/how-can-i-kill-myself) // [Why should I take showers?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159672/why-should-i-take-showers) The last one is especially funny seeing as how this kinda references a popular gaming stereotype.

Answer (score 23):

Only if the other side of the shirt has the answer!

[image: Crappy mockup]

(I apologize for the crappy mockup.)

Comment: *cough really long domain name being graphically a pain in the arse cough*

Comment: I love it. I considered putting the answer on the back, yeah, just forgot to put it in the question.

Comment: You should really get that cough checked out

Comment: +1 for "stackexhcange"

Comment: Hey, @badp. How about a design update with the name Arqade? A bit easier to fit in?

Comment: [arqade.com](http://arqade.com) actually does redirect to [gaming.stackexchange.com](http://gaming.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 15):

You missed:

- [My wife is stuck in a wall, can I save her?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5542/my-wife-is-stuck-in-a-wall-can-i-save-her)
- [How can I tell if a corpse is safe to eat?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-corpse-is-safe-to-eat)
- [How can I keep monsters out of my nether regions?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14605/how-can-i-keep-monsters-out-of-my-nether-regions)
- [Can I pass out from excessive drinking?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9768/can-i-pass-out-from-excessive-drinking)
- [How do I know if I'm dead?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11455/how-do-i-know-if-im-dead)

Would the shirts be something like this?

> ## ```
> My children are useless.
> ```
>
> ## ```
>    What should I do?
> ```
>
> #### ```
>      gaming.stackexchange.com
> ```

Answer (score 7):

[Why did my dog just eat my cat?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/17067/8366)
[My pet is a public menace, what did I do wrong?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/26210/8366)
[Why make cheese if milk is already food?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/27010/8366)

There are a few others that might not always strike the same chord with everyone ... I think you can browse the Dwarf Fortress questions and see which ones I mean.

Answer (score 7):

How about:

- [Is it dangerous to go extreme pig riding in a thunderstorm?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21261/is-it-dangerous-to-go-extreme-pig-riding-in-a-thunderstorm)
- [Does hitting a sheep in the face yield more wool?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24696/does-hitting-a-sheep-in-the-face-yield-more-wool)
- [What happens when you reach the edge of the world?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/19179/what-happens-when-you-reach-the-edge-of-the-world)
- [My dog keeps catching on fire, what should I do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28245/my-dog-keeps-catching-on-fire-what-should-i-do)
- [What happened to my face?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13441/what-happened-to-my-face)

Answer (score 5):

Cmon, Saints Row 3 makes this almost too easy.

[Where can I find an unattractive, overweight woman of leisure?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39265/where-can-i-find-an-unattractive-overweight-woman-of-leisure)

[What's the easiest way to maximize profits from Insurance Fraud?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39176/whats-the-easiest-way-to-maximize-profits-from-insurance-fraud)

[While streaking, can I "shock" police officers?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38877/while-streaking-can-i-shock-police-officers)

[How can I most efficiently launch myself through my car's windshield?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38508/how-can-i-most-efficiently-launch-myself-through-my-cars-windshield)

[Can I get credit for lewd gestures at people who are already trying to kill me?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38144/can-i-get-credit-for-lewd-gestures-at-people-who-are-already-trying-to-kill-me)

[What's the most effective way to make Nut Shots?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36799/whats-the-most-effective-way-to-make-nut-shots)

Answer (score 4):

A few more, courtesy of The Witcher series.

[What are the consequences of accepting unknown substances from strange men?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23361/what-are-the-consequences-of-accepting-unknown-substances-from-strange-men)

[I lost all my stuff after a night of hard drinking... Can I get it back?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22957/lost-all-my-stuff-after-a-night-of-hard-drinking)

[What's the best way to sober up?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22874/whats-the-best-way-to-sober-up)

[How do I get sex from the woman in the village?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/27846/how-do-i-get-sex-from-the-woman-in-the-village-murky-vaters)

I'm particularly fond of the unknown substances from strange men question...

Answer (score 4):

Some More:

- [How can I change my clothes?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23618/how-can-i-change-my-clothes) <- great for on a shirt ;)
- [How can I tell teammates from spies?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18782/how-can-i-tell-whether-or-not-my-friend-will-backstab-me)
- [How can I keep monsters out of my nether regions?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14605/how-can-i-keep-monsters-out-of-my-nether-regions)
- [How can I tell if a stalker is going to kill me?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39487/how-can-i-tell-if-a-stalker-is-going-to-kill-me)
- [How can I get my wife to stop nagging about a few murders?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39411/how-can-i-get-my-wife-to-stop-nagging-about-a-few-murders)
- [How can I summon a meteorite?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23031/how-can-i-summon-a-meteorite)

Comment: `How can I tell whether or not my friend will backstab me?` is great for the back of a shirt.

Answer (score 4):

And then [the-stick-of-truth](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-stick-of-truth) happened...

- [What happens if I fart on someone's balls?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/159461/42984)
- [Where can I find a dog to fart on?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/159373/42984)
- [Is there any advantage in getting a nosejob?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/159206/42984)
- [How can I beat Al Gore in a fight?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/159121/42984)
- [Where can I find homeless people to beat up?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/159104/42984)
- [Where can I find Jesus Christ?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/158727/42984)
- [Is investing money at the bank just a scam?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/158728/42984)
- [How can I make the mean goth kids talk to me and be my friends?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/158726/42984)
- [Al Gore won't leave me alone. How do I unfriend someone on Facebook?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/158984/42984)