# Would you be interested in printable Gaming.SE posters, to give out and/or put in your local gaming store?

Tags: discussion, swag

Adding to the long list of things to Get Done, here's another idea that [FallenAngelEyes](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/114/fallenangeleyes) brought up and discussed with us in [the Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-b-ridge) yesterday.

Basically, would you all be interested in a printable PDF poster that advertises Gaming.SE, for placement in your local gaming stores (or coffee shops/bulletin boards/highly trafficked refrigerators)? The poster could/should/would include:

- the Gaming.SE logo
- the site URL
- a brief blurb about what the site is
- some ever-popular [question titles](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2521/would-you-like-gaming-se-merch-with-classic-questions-on-them)

If this is something that you would be interested in using to spread the good word of Stack Exchange in your neck of the woods, let us know. If you have any suggestions about what should and shouldn't be put on the poster, definitely let us know. If you don't like me using the term "neck of the woods," *keep that to yourself*.

**UPDATE**

Apologies for dropping the ball on this, but I want to get it up and going again! Similar talks have [taken place in the DIY Meta](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/378/what-should-our-flyers-handouts-say) and I want to reignite the conversation here. Does anyone have a catchy slogan to pitch? If so, please respond! I want to get these posters designed and put up here pronto!

Comment: I dislike your using the term "neck of the woods."

Comment: +1, I love this idea!

Comment: We still have a long URL

Comment: Posters are cool for a lot of reasons, one of them being that you can fit more text on them (al la [trainspotting](http://cache2.allpostersimages.com/p/LRG/7/713/ZYKA000Z/posters/trainspotting.jpg) ).  It would be cool if I could get a poster of my favorite _answer_.

Comment: Posters have been made and are availible on this question:
http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2968/gaming-promotional-posters

Answer (score 8):

[Yes](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1588567#1588567)

Comment: What he said...

Comment: I wonder how hard it would be to convince local sites to hang them up though

Comment: @Ivo Something we're going to have to address on a case by case basis I guess. I think smaller game stores may be more open to this than large corporate chains. For example, I'll be asking my local store which is only 3 stores total rather than Free Record Shop or Game Mania, who are much larger.

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes Even bigger chains tend to be franchised and could be open to this kind of thing. I've had success with it once (was about something else though)

Answer (score 6):

I *really* like this idea, and already voiced in chat I know a local game store that would most likely be willing to hang up posters.

With that said, I do think we need to be careful about the kind of questions we advertise on the posters. Although I think that our list of [awesome titles](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2521/would-you-like-gaming-se-merch-with-classic-questions-on-them) is awesome, it's possible they could turn some people off who might think the [site is intended as a joke,](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2548/i-cant-tell-if-posts-are-a-joke-or-not) and not to be taken seriously.
Not to say we shouldn't choose [awesome titles](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2521/would-you-like-gaming-se-merch-with-classic-questions-on-them), but as users who frequent the site we know that these titles are meant to be in good fun, and are not an indication we are not serious about answering questions.

Once again, I'm not saying we shouldn't choose awesome titles, I think we should. We just need to keep in mind that certain awesome titles can give people the wrong impression.

Comment: This is definitely something worth considering when we get to the layout phase. I totally agree that it could portray the site in a different light than we intend. Keeping that in mind!