# Gaming promotional posters

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, advertisements

As addressed in [this question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2565/would-you-be-interested-in-printable-gaming-se-posters-to-give-out-and-or-put-in) I have made some posters for anyone to print out and advertise the site. Please feel free to use them as you please.

[image: Get stuck]
[image: Desu Desu]
[image: Safe to eat]
[image: Adorable animals]
[image: Game on]
[image: If I'm dead]

Please don't post suggestions here, ask me personally in chat.

Comment: I think we can all agree the one where @mana is about to be back stabbed is the best one.

Comment: Love the Diggle reference

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks the untucked shirt corner makes this guy look like Steve?

Comment: @Ronan I really like the designs in general, as they're very fun, but I am loathe to print them off myself because of the black backgrounds and how much ink they would use from my printer. :( Using black paper would not help because the white areas would be filled in. :/ Can you possibly make a white bg design?

Comment: If you up the error correction on the QR code, you can add the heart icon as part of QR code. See this hack: http://hackaday.com/2011/08/11/how-to-put-your-logo-in-a-qr-code/ You QR code become bigger as a trade off.